# How to return "not found" when return value is const reference

Tags: c++, reference

I have a problem that when I use  something like this:

```
const MyList& my_list = getListForThisRegion(/*region ID, ...*/);
```

I dont know what to return when no value is found.

My problem is that I would like to have a way to signal (when returning value from `getListForThisRegion`) "value not found" to the caller. If I was returning a pointer, I could return `nullptr`, but I don't know how to do it with references. All I can think of is having some static member `not_found` of type `MyList`, and returning a reference to it, but it seems ugly.

And yes, I can't return value because lists are "fat" and often used.

EDIT: ton of great answers , but exception is not an acceptable solution because the number of times it would be raised is high (the percentage `nbNotFound/nbCalls` is high).
EDIT2: regarding boost::optional - how complicated it is to master? I mean does it require some non obvious knowledge (non obvious= something that is not simply knowing the syntax)?

Comment: throwing an exception can be a good option.

Comment: you might also want to look at `boost::optional`

Comment: A reference has to refer to an object, so you either throw an exception or don't use a reference. `boost::optional` is a great choice, but that may be overkill; just use a pointer.

Comment: You can do same thing as I suggested here (basic idea): [notify the caller of not found element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376985/invalid-initialization-of-non-const-reference-when-returning-an-array-element)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two idiomatic ways to handle this:

- Change your interface to return a type that has the ability to refer to nothing (e.g. a pointer that can be null, an iterator to `end`).

Or

- Throw an exception if the item isn't found.

---

Returning a dummy object is a bit hacky, and you don't gain anything over returning a pointer as you still have to check the result against a special value (null or the dummy object).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: that would change the semantics to return by value rather than reference (unless you return an optional reference, but I don't see what that adds to a pointer).

Comment: @Mike: How about `boost::optional<boost::reference_wrapper<MyList> >`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, agreed. It depends on the type what is best. For larger object types I tend to use a pointer, and for small/fundamentals an optional.

Comment: @FredOverflow: You could, but `MyList const *` gives the same semantics, lower runtime cost, const-correctness, and less verbosity, so I'd prefer that.

Comment: @FredOverflow: When used as a return type, I don't see that `boost::optional<boost::reference_wrapper<MyList> >` provides any benefit over `MyList*`.

Comment: @Joe: returning an optional reference instead of a pointer prevents the user of the function from wondering wheter he must release the memory himself or not.

Comment: @Luc: There's no need to wonder about that. If it returns an unmanaged pointer then either the caller is not responsible for it, or it needs to be rewritten to return a smart pointer.

Comment: @Mike: I guess you're right, smart pointers can indeed be used to make the ownership policy explicit, making return by pointer the best solution here.

Answer (score 3):

How about rewriting the function to take reference to "returnValue" where you put the list to return? Then the function can return boolean value indicating found/ not found.

```
bool getListForThisRegion(/*region ID, ...*/, MyList& ret_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write exception class (hierarchy, if needed) and throw an exception for such case.

Answer (score 1):

I only see two possibilities: either you have a special member in the MyList class declaring that an instance is "null" (not set) or you could throw an exception.

Comment: Having a member in `MyList` to indicate the null value seems very intrusive. This kind of feature is often better achieved by wrapping the object into another one. `Boost.Optional<T>` provides such a wrapper for representing a nullable object.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow `std::map`'s lead, and insert a default constructed list into your container, and return a reference to that.  Obviously, this depends on there not being a semantic difference between a default list, and a list that isn't there at all.

You can also add a query function that searches for a particular region, and returns true if it has a list, and false otherwise.  Then, you can throw an exception in your accessor safe in the knowledge that it will not be a common occurrence.