# What to return when a std::map::at goes out_of_range?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

In a game I would like to search a map of items and return the one located on a particular square of the board.  But what if the square is empty?  (The items are not stored in the board structure.  Never mind about that for the purposes of this question.)  I have the code below, but what should I do to return an "empty" reference?

```
map<pair<int, int>, Item*> _items;

Item& itemAt(int row, int col) const {
    try {  
        return *_items.at(make_pair(row, col));
    } catch(out_of_range& e) {
        return // what goes here?            
    } 
}
```

Or is this the wrong approach and I should just use `find()`?

Comment: nitpick: since you do not modify `e`, catch by `const`-reference.

Comment: looks like duplicate of this Q of mine... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847336/how-to-return-not-found-when-return-value-is-const-reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, using a pointer as a means to represent "zero or one object" is useful:

```
Item* itemAt(int row, int col) const {
    try {
        return _items.at(make_pair(row, col));
    } catch(out_of_range& e) {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

However, using `std::map::find()` is probably a faster and cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Based on your answers my code now looks like this:

    Item* itemAt(int row, int col) const {
        auto item = _impl._items.find(make_pair(row, col));
        if (item == _impl._items.end()) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        return item->second.get();
    }

Answer (score 12):

If not finding an item is not an error condition in your program, then you should **not return a reference** (since references cannot be null). Rather, you should return a (non-owning, most likely) pointer, and return `nullptr` in case the item was not found:

```
Item* itemAt(int row, int col) const {
    try {  
        return _items.at(make_pair(row, col));
    } catch(out_of_range& e) {
        return nullptr;
    }   
}
```

On the other hand, if not finding an item is an error, then you can return a reference (when the item is found) and **let the exception propagate** when the item is not found - the responsibility of handling it would belong to the part of your code that has strategic knowledge on how to handle it:

```
Item& itemAt(int row, int col) const {
    return *_items.at(make_pair(row, col));
}
```

Comment: I was not able to work on this game until now but belated thanks to all who responded.  It is quite possible that a given square on the grid will not contain an Item so I went with your first approach and I now return an Item pointer or nullptr if the square is empty.

Answer (score 3):

If it is an error for client code to request an item that does not exist then `throw` an exception to report the failure and return an `Item&`.

If it is not an error, as the `value_type` of the `map` is already an `Item*` change the return type to be a `Node*` and return [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) to indicate that at item at the requested position does not exist and use [`map::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

To avoid lifetime problems, which already exist with `Item&` return type, consider changing the `value_type` to be a [`std::shared_ptr<Item>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). If client code has a reference or a raw pointer to a value with the `map` and that element is removed from the `map` then the client is left with a dangling pointer/reference. Switching to a `std::shared_ptr<Item>` avoids this scenario. The `itemAt()` function would return a `std::shared_ptr<Item>`. This also has the benefit that the `Item`s in the `map` do not need to be explicitly `delete`d.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did not include it in my original question for simplicities sake but my map actually contains unique_ptr<Item>'s.  So I use item->get() to return a disposable pointer as the return value

Answer (score 1):

Actually other people have had the same problem:

- some of them wrote [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)
- you can return a pair of pointer and return value
- you can throw an exception
- you can return a [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#C.2B.2B)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. boost::optional seems like the most elegant solution out of those you mention but as I mention in my other comments I ultimately went with just returning nullptr if an item was not found.