# What will return if no map element found?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, vector

My C++ header has some code snippets like the following:

```
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short> > > m_usIRDataPool;

public:
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short> >& IRChannelData(std::string sChannelName);
```

In its implementation file (.cpp), `IRChannelData()` has the following definition:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short> >& MyClass::IRChannelData(std::string sChannelName)
{   
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short> > >::iterator it = m_usIRDataPool.find( sChannelName );

    if ( it != m_usIRDataPool.end() )
    {  
       return it->second;
    }

  //  return ????; // How can I return?
}
```

So, what will return if no entry is found (vector of vector) in the `m_usIRDataPool` map container to get rid of

```
warning C4715: 'MyClass::IRChannelData' : not all control paths return a value.
```

Comment: Are you asking what *should* you return?  Or are you asking what will return if you don't return anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [invalid initialization of non-const reference when returning an array element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376985/invalid-initialization-of-non-const-reference-when-returning-an-array-element)

Comment: @Ben: The last sentence seems to indicate the former.

Comment: If the entry does not exist what is the rest of the program supposed to do? Is it always supposed to exit? Or are you supposed to create something if it does not exist? What you return will depend on how you expect the callers of the function to react (it may not return anything an exception may be appropriate).

Answer (score 3):

- Return a `bool` indicating success/failure and return the address of the result vector via an "out" semantics parameter, or
- throw an exception if no element found in map

Comment: Thank you and good idea. I'll keep in mind of your suggestion in my future programming.

Answer (score 0):

Return a pointer and return `0` in case you don't find what you're looking for.

Comment: @GoldenLee: You should not edit your question with the answer given, otherwise all answers will become meaningless. I rollbacked your edit.

Answer (score 0):

As you're returning the reference to something, you cannot declare an empty map on the function and then return it. What you can do is declare a variable in MyClass `MyClass::emptyReturnMap` of the same type you want to return `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short> >`, and then return it. But if you're editing the contents of it (as the return is not const), you're gonna have to clear it on every call.

Comment: Thank you! Is there nothing I can do but declaring an empty vector of vector like std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short> > m_v2DEmpty;? If this is the case, I'd rather return a pointer instead.

Comment: No, as a reference is going through, it must be available after the function is over, if you declare it inside the function, once the function goes out of scope, the variable will be lost and you'll get a memory access error. The variable could be static though.